# Turn php foreach "echo" into a variable

Tags: php

How do I make this php foreach echo into a variable?

```
 <?php
       include 'database.php';
               $pdo = Database::connect();
               $sql = 'SELECT town FROM shows';
               foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

               echo  "' " . $row['town'] . " ' ,";

               }

               Database::disconnect();

?>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: please read some book (apress, o'reilly, headfirst) to get some understanding of the language

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? You should loop through the query results, not run the query n-times.

Comment: What is the expected output vs. what you are getting?  Are you actually selecting any data from your result set?  Is your query even producing a result set?

Comment: Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the basic concepts of the language. I'm with @Ejay - go pick up a book, this site is meant to help people who show a basic understanding and you don't.

Comment: Yeah I getting results and I have results in a correct format for Google Calendar API. As apposed to echoing the data i would like to have it as a variable to input into javascript on Google Calendar.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it will probably not be useful to any _programmer_. This question shows lack of understanding of basics of programming

Comment: `How do I make this php foreach echo an variable?` and now you say `As apposed to echoing the data i would like to have it as a variable` Be clearer, please. Are you trying to build a js array? a json?

Comment: Guys, understand what your are saying and its noted with thanks. Though its because of this site, w3schools etc that I can do some programming now and build some basic applications, thus the two answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple concatenation.
(Assuming your query actually works and some entries were there to be queried and that your question was to "echo" into a variable)

```
<?php
  include 'database.php';

  $pdo = Database::connect();
  $sql = 'SELECT town FROM shows';
  $foo = "";
  foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $foo .= "' " . $row['town'] . " ' ,";
  }
  echo $foo;
  Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to be an array, you could do it like:

`$myarray[]="' " . $row['town'] . " ' ,";`

After that you can get it with `echo $myarray[(numberofrow)];`

If you want it to be one variable:
`$myvar .= "' " . $row['town'] . " ' ,";`